# Find (x, y) where a line crosses +-10 y or +-10 x

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

The Image is a sketch of what I’m trying to solve
The value of x isn’t fixed at 45 it can be any value from 0-360 I used 45 as an example and the value Y To show what coordinates I need to find

So what formulas will I need as I’m aware trigonometry is something I’ll need but I’ve never been able to understand it

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it just me or are there two different meanings for $x$ in the picture? It's the coordinate and the angle ... That's confusing.

Comment: So what I think is that you have to split this into four cases, according to the four quadrants. Once you know which quadrant you're in, the problem becomes very easy.

Comment: To be more precise, you want the intersection of the ray $y=x\tan\theta$ with the boundary of the square with vertices $(\pm10,\pm10)$. Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry Ik it’s confusing yes the boundary is +-10 x and +-10 y the graph on the right is an example for after I’ve identified what quadrant the answer is in based of the angle x

Comment: As you can see from the picture, in certain regions **the $x$-coordinate of the intersection is constant** and in other regions **the $y$-coordinate of the intersection is constant**. You should split it up into different cases and you'll see ...

Comment: Actually, I realised now that it's eight different cases, not four. The situation changes every $45^{\circ}$.

Comment: I’ve realised if I separate each quadrant into regions of 45 degree intervals x/y will be consistent so I can use them values along with the angle and use basic trig to caculate x/y thanks for the help Matti P